# CiviCRM password length in Joomla

Tags: forms, gdpr

I'm working on a version of CiviCRM installed in Joomla, I'm using a registration form with custom fields of Civi for the registration.
The problem is that CiviCRM does not apply the same checks on passwords as Joomla does.
I have not found solutions in the system, so I'm trying to insert custom controls using hooks.
As indicated I created a file and specified the path and customize the code find on CiviCRM guide for my purpose, but does not detect any changes on the form I'm using.

```
function joomla_civicrm_validateForm( $formName, &$fields, &$files, &$form, &$errors ) {
  if ($formName == 'Edit') {
    foreach ($fields['cms_pass'] as $key => $password) {
      if(strlen(trim($password)) > 8) {
        $errors['cms_pass[' . $key . ']'] = ts('Password must be 8 characters');
      }
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: CiviCRM uses the CMS for managing users and passwords so it is not managing passwords separately from Joomla.  Can you explain a bit more about your form, how it is being called and where it appears Civi is not checking the password?

Comment: Hello. I am using the form "Name and adress" (default in CIVI) with "Account creation required " active, but, the password field don't do any of the Joomla control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found an example on the Civi Wiki and, with a bit of workaround, it finally works:

```
function joomla_civicrm_validateForm($formName, &$fields, &$files, &$form, &$errors) {  

  $errors = array();

  // check we're targeting the right form
  if ($formName == 'Edit') {
    return true;
  }

   $password = CRM_Utils_Array::value( 'cms_pass', $fields );

   // ensure that password is present and valid
   if (!$password) {
      $errors['cms_pass'] = ts( 'Password is a required field' );
   } elseif (strlen($password) < 50) {
      $errors['cms_pass'] = ts( 'Password must be longer than 50 characters');
   }

  return empty($errors) ? true : $errors;
}
```